# Styling a mermaid node in a markdown file via css

Tags: css, markdown, mermaid

I would like to customize globally my Mermaid diagram in a Markdown file.

I declare a style balise and put : green2 > rect that enable to change style of a node in Mermaid. The problem is that the caption "Node A" don't change its color.

```
A[Node A]:::green2--> B[Node B];
```

However if i put this it works perfectly:

```
classDef green2 fill:#01ff70,stroke:#000,stroke-width:2px,color:#000
```

Here the css :

```css
<style>

.green2 > rect {
    fill:#01ff70 !important;
    stroke:#000 !important;
    stroke-width:2px !important;
    color : rgb(173,216,230);

}

</style>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Could you send your JavaScript code for rendering the Mermaid.js diagram, I can't reproduce on the Mermaid Live Editor.

Comment: I'm sorry but I use mermaid in markdown with a css stylesheet so there is no JS...

Comment: Hmmm... then it should be something related to the styles not reaching the scope of the mermaid diagram. I can copy paste the styles that you provided in the Mermaid Live Editor and everything works fine.